# Getting TypeError at / expected string or bytes-like object in QuerySet

Tags: python, django

I tried to run runserver, I checked all the pages, everything was fine except my homepage which issued an error. TypeError at / expected string or bytes-like object.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Desktop\Learn Django\cloneBlogProject\mySite\blog\views.py", line 19, in get_queryset
    return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now).order_by('-published_date')
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1350, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1311, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1165, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 72, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1355, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1215, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1316, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "C:\Users\ANTON\Anaconda3\envs\cloneBlog\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateparse.py", line 107, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: expected string or bytes-like object
```

And this error points to the views.py source code in that class.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.utils import timezone

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte = timezone.now).order_by('-published_date')
```

This is my models.py file.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)


    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now
        self.save()

    def approveComments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approveComments=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Please help me to solve the error. Thank you.

Comment: `timezone.now` is a function, not a static attribute.  In your filter statement you are not _calling_ the function, as you have left off the parentheses `()` at the end.  i.e. you probably want `published_date__lte = timezone.now()`.